# Tags: content-search vs search

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have tags [search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) and [content-search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-search) which are both used frequently. Some questions even use both, but I don't see the difference. So, should we merge them? And merge to search or to content-search?

There could be a difference in the tags if content-search was about the `ContentSearch` api and search was more related to actual search solutions in Sitecore based sites, but I'm not sure people would really understand that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) is too non-specific. It would be covered by either the [solr](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solr) or [lucene](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucene) tags. [content-search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-search) is a specific technology however; basically whenever using Sitecore's abstraction layer to either `solr` or `lucene`.

I'd suggest merging [search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) into [content-search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-search) and put a synonym up, to the same effect. And then expand the Wiki for the [content-search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-search) tag so it explains usage; and that it should not be used when [solr](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solr) or [lucene](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucene) is more appropriate.

Comment: As an example: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/is-there-a-weighting-involved-with-sitecore-contentsearch-searchtypes-searchre

This is a content-search question, not really specifically lucene

Comment: I agree with this, seems a sensible approach

Comment: Good points, let's go with `content-search` then.

Comment: Apparently I cannot create the synonym, so that will be up to you guys I'm afraid. Is there something I can do to help with the "merge"? (guess not as you probably have a simple merge button)

Comment: Sorry, thought someone did this already. Executed the tag merge now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Their general usage looks the same to me.

I would suggest merging them, keeping `search` and making `content-search` a synonym.